# Uber Integration with IOS

Tags: uber-api

We are trying to create a POC for our existing IOS application where on a particular event/particular page a user of the system would get an option to book an Uber.

This is the first time I would be working with Uber API's. Would need some help on the implementation. Not getting any tutorials which could guide me(google search).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This likely is not a great question for StackOverflow as it does not include any question about code or any specific technical implementation or problem.

In response to your question, here is an intro w/ docs on how to implement what you are looking for: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/introduction   Googling "Uber API" points to the developer.uber.com website. Cheers.